# Eloquent and Mysql Phpmyadmin returning different results

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, phpmyadmin, eloquent

Eloquent created sql but not returning any result but if i copy the generated sql into phpmyadmin it is returning right results.

Eloquent code

```
$deliveries=$deliveries->where(function ($query)use($type) 
{
    foreach ($type as $condition) {
        $query->orWhere('status','\''.$condition.'\'');
    }

})->where('assigned_to','\''.$user->id.'\'')
->filtered(\App::make(\App\Filters\DeliveryFilter::class))
->whereRaw('dropoff_zipcode IN (\''.$service_zip_codes.'\')')
->get();
```

Generated SQL

```
select * from `deliveries` where (`status` = 'accepted' or `status` = 'in transit') and `assigned_to` = '56' and dropoff_zipcode IN ('390012','390010','390007','390020')
```

Comment: may be different database connections?

Comment: try to output results var_dump($deliveries);

Comment: No, i am using same database connection and if i am running a db::select() with the generated query it is returning the same exact result, but not with the eloquent way.

Comment: @Alex var_dump result object(Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection)#466 (1) { ["items":protected]=> array(0) { } } []

Comment: by using toSql() at place of get() check your raw query from eloquent.. and compare both

Comment: @DCoder string(146) "select * from `deliveries` where (`status` = ? or `status` = ?) and `assigned_to` = ? and dropoff_zipcode IN ('390012','390010','390007','390020')"

Comment: Make sure the query generated is putting the brackets round the or part (status) otherwise this will cause problems.

Comment: try to use: $deliveries = DB::table('deliveries')->where(...)->get();

Comment: show your complete eloquent ..?

Comment: @DCoder Yes showing complete eloquent statement i am not sure about ? in status

Comment: then where you use DB::Select or DB::table....?

Comment: @DCoder For testing purpose i did this. I don't actually know how to change make status dynamic as per inputs from user `$deliveries = DB::select("select * from `deliveries` where (`status` = 'accepted' or `status` = 'in transit') and `assigned_to` = $user->id and dropoff_zipcode IN ('$service_zip_codes')");`